# Is it true that $f(X|Y, Y+Z) = f(X|Y, Z)$?

Tags: random-variable, conditional-probability

Is it true that $f(X|Y, Y+Z) = f(X|Y, Z)$? My guess is it is true as if I know the realizations of $Y$ and $Y+Z$, then I can recover the realization of $Z$. But I am not sure how I can show it is true mathematical.

Comment: Mathematics says $Z=(Y+Z)-Y.$ Thus, knowledge of the full distribution of $(Y,Z)$ is equivalent to knowledge of the full distribution of $(Y,Y+Z).$